# How to get the relationship between backup set?

Tags: oracle, backup, rman

We use command `backup database` to perform a full backup, serval backup sets are generated during the backup operation.
Also, we use list backup to show the backup information, the output as followed:

```
BS Key  Size       Device Type Elapsed Time Completion Time
------- ---------- ----------- ------------ ---------------
7       136M       DISK        00:00:20     04-NOV-06      
        BP Key: 7   Status: AVAILABLE  Compressed: NO  Tag: TAG20071104T200759
        Piece Name: /d2/RDBMS/backupset/2007_11_04/o1_mf_annnn_TAG20071104T200759_ztjxx3k8_.bkp

  List of Archived Logs in backup set 7
  Thrd Seq     Low SCN    Low Time  Next SCN   Next Time
  ---- ------- ---------- --------- ---------- ---------
  1    1       173832     21-OCT-06 174750     21-OCT-06
  1    2       174750     21-OCT-06 174755     21-OCT-06
  1    3       174755     21-OCT-06 174758     21-OCT-06

BS Key  Type LV Size       Device Type Elapsed Time Completion Time
------- ---- -- ---------- ----------- ------------ ---------------
8       Full    2M         DISK        00:00:01     04-NOV-06      
        BP Key: 8   Status: AVAILABLE  Compressed: NO  Tag: TAG20071104T200829
        Piece Name: /disk1/oracle/dbs/c-774627068-20071104-01
  Controlfile Included: Ckp SCN: 631510       Ckp time: 04-NOV-06
  SPFILE Included: Modification time: 21-OCT-06
```

From above output, I could not figure out whether such backup sets are generated by the same command, `backup database`. Is there any available command to satisfy my requirement?

Comment: The first one is the backup itself, the 2nd is a controlfile backup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, before firing up rman, set the os enviornment variable NLS_DATE_FORMAT to include the time, something like 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss' or 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'.  Then when you do something like 'list backup' (anything that reports date/time) you will get the date and time, not just the time.

Second, read up on the TAG command.  If you do not specify a TAG, the default value is date and time.  All backup pieces/sets taken from the same BACKUP command will have the same TAG value.

Answer (score 0):

From SQL:

```
SELECT p.start_time, p.handle, p.tag, s.backup_type, 
       s.incremental_level, controlfile_included
FROM   v$backup_piece p, v$backup_set s
WHERE  p.set_stamp = s.set_stamp
AND    p.set_count = s.set_count
ORDER BY tag;
```

For the backup type:

```
L: Archived Redo Logs
D: Datafile Full Backup (or control file backup or autobackup)
I: Incremental Backup
```

You can see which files are in each backup by the TAG column.

Keep in mind that this view may report backups are don't actually exist on disk unless you:

```
RMAN> crosscheck backup;
RMAN> delete expired backup;
```

Refer to the Oracle Database 12c Documentation (or whatever version of Oracle you are using) for more information:

[v$backup_set](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-1502768C-118E-4101-98D7-F9B82F7F262F.htm#REFRN30025)

[v$backup_piece](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-01D14739-4AF6-4006-AE3A-345DAF893D89.htm#REFRN30023)

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a backup script which inserted a row into a backup table at the beginning of a backup returning a sequence number. I then had the following in my backup script and when the backup finished I updated my backup table with the end time and success or fail. Since my backup table had the server name and backup time, I could write a report joining my backup table with the rsr table to get a detailed backup report send to my email every day letting me know what backups happened the night before, as well as a section for each database and its last backup and finally a section on databases that have not had a full backup in over a week. It helped me to manage the databases since we had over 100 databases to backup. You can certainly use the command_id to gather all of the parts of any backup in a similar fashion. FYI if you backup a pre 10g database the rsr table is not used, therefore this won't work.

```
SET COMMAND ID TO '${pkey}';
```